# What is the point of Release Provisioning Profile under Build Settings in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

What is the point of selecting a Release Provisioning Profile under "Build Settings" in Xcode? 
When I archive the application as "ad hoc" or "enterprise deployment" a new Provision Profile is selected that is not necessarily the one selected in "Build Settings".

If I look at the embedded.mobileprovision inside the packaged IPA file, the profile always points to the provision selected in the archiving step (Screenshot 2)

Is the Release Provisioning Profile in "Build Settings" used at all in my cases?

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhSxT.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roVbS.png)